# Macro not working as expected

Tags: macro, vscode

I have a list such as follows

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

I am trying to write a macro that will get it in this format (I am writing a .yaml file)

```
  - "apple"
  - "banana"
  - "cherry"
```

I recorded my macro with `qa` and typed `v}geI  - "<Esc>v}geA"<Esc>`, then stopped recording with `q`.

When I replayed my macro using `@a` my result was

```
 apple"
 banana"
 cherry"
```

so there is a single space where there should be   `- "`.
I even tried replaying my macro on the same chunk of code where I recorded it (after undoing it) and got the same results.

I've also included a screenshot of the macro view when I run `:reg`.

I'm using vim 1.21.5 on vscode.

Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot of macro view]

Comment: Your macro seems needlessly complicated. Try to achieve what you want manually first, then record that keystrokes. I'd probably go with something like this: `^V}I- "^[^VGA^[^VG$A"^[` where `^V` means `Ctrl-V` and `^[` means `Esc`.

Comment: Could be a vscode bug.